# How to glue two dependent tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, outer-join

I have Customer and Application tables. I want to create select query which provides info about a customer and also to count a number of applications user has in the system.

```
select distinct c.id, c.region, c.city, count(a.customer_id_id) 
from customers c
join applications a on c.id=a.customer_id_id
group by c.id;
```

But I get an error that I need to group by region and city but I want to display info about each application not to group by region and city. Because in such a way I will get not a number of applications for each user but for each group of users.
I read that it's possible to do with nested queries and full outer join but I tried and it didn't work. Can you explain to me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close.

1. Use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` so that `Customers` with 0 records in `Applications` will also be included (assuming your intent here)
2. Don't use `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` together. Distinct means "If all the fields are the same value across multiple records in the record set produced by this SELECT statement, then only give back distinct records, dropping the duplicates". Instead with `GROUP BY`, "Group by this list of fields. Any remaining fields not in this list will be aggregated using a formula in your SELECT clause like `count(a.customer_id_id)`." They are similar, but you can't aggregate a field with merely a DISTINCT.
3. When using `GROUP BY`, if you are not going to aggregate a field with an aggregation formula (`count`, `sum`, `avg`, etc..) then you must include it in your group by. This isn't necessary with some RDBMS (older versions of MySQL, for example) but it's poor practice since a field that isn't explicitly aggregated with a formula that is also missing from the `GROUP BY` is like telling the RDBMS "Just pick which ever value you wish from matching records" which might have some unexpected consequences.

---

```
SELECT c.id, c.region, c.city, count(a.customer_id_id) 
FROM customers c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN applications a on c.id=a.customer_id_id
GROUP BY c.id, c.region, c.city;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your problem is. I assume that region and city are functionally dependent of id (that is id is a candidate key). Newer versions of postgresql will therefor accept your query. However, if you're on an older version you can expand your group by clause to:

```
select c.id, c.region, c.city, count(a.customer_id_id)  
from customers c
join applications a 
    on c.id=a.customer_id_id
group by c.id, c.region, c.city;
```

You say that you would like to display information about each application, but why are you then counting the number of applications per customer? Do you mean something like:

```
select c.id, c.region, c.city, a.customer_id_id, a.<other attributes>  
from customers c
join applications a 
    on c.id=a.customer_id_id;
```